# ASP.net - membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have created a user using the built-in CreateUserWizard - control.

I can now log-in using the built-in Login - control.

But where is the data stored in the database?

I am using SQL Server 2005 Express and I have also sql server 2000 running on my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the app_data folder, which is a part of your project. There should be a database file in there. Unless you manually created the aspnetdb, using the aspnet_regsql.exe command, a database will be created for you in that folder.

Comment: How can I use sql 2000 for membership?

Comment: google the aspnet_regsql.exe command. It is used to create all the tables you need. Here is a pretty good walkthrough for using it with sql 2000. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx

Comment: Where can I find the window used in Step 3...'new ASP.NET Admin MMC Snap-in now provides a GUI based way...'?

Comment: Ahh yes, that would be use if you were using IIS to host your pages. When you click on the virtual directory for your site in IIS there is a new ASP.net page. Since i'm assuming you are just using the built in visual studio host (You click run or debug and the page just opens), you can just edit the web.config.

Comment: Correction: Not ASP.net page, I meant ASP.net tab.

Answer (score 0):

In some tables.

Typically named:

- aspnet_Membership
- aspnet_Users
- and friends

Comment: How can I configure my Web project to use membership from sql 2000?

Comment: Point the connection string to that database? No?

Comment: There is no ConnectionString in my Web.config file. But my application is working. How is it possible?

Comment: What? It makes no difference who accepted you; I was just saying that his post has the answers you need!

Comment: Where can I find the window used in Step 3...'new ASP.NET Admin MMC Snap-in now provides a GUI based way'?